# how to implement duplication attack in contiki-2.7?

Tags: file, security, duplicates, simulation, procedure

I saw a tutorial which explains for applying a attack you should have an attack file than you have to create motes . But I am not able to understand from where I should get an attack file . Can anyone help with this ... how to implement a duplication attack ion contiki ? I am new to contiki , can anyone give a clarity on this .

I tried making 10 motes of a udp sender file.c which was present in contiki and 1 mote of udp sink.c which was also present in contiki folder and I observed various parameters like power consumption , network diagram . For creating motes , I need files . For the above case there were two files present in contiki/ examples / ipv6 folder.